# how do you do or within ifelse in data.table package in r

Tags: r, data.table

I have this data frame called final:

dput(head(final))

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1468268220, 1468269840, 1468268160, 
1468268700, 1468268760, 1468268940), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), Trans = c(1454L, 816L, 1144L, 2542L, 200L, 180L
), Cpu = c(64L, 40L, 56L, 61L, 16L, 11L), HeapUsage = c(57.0708814590398, 
80.9735869076328, 48.902594693305, 94.0288575990024, 69.2328919834884, 
82.9988047593942), upper = c(65.8548134294912, 42.4943251956111, 
51.6875408154387, 84.6919764584793, 23.1855269194862, 22.5880538495753
), lower = c(45.1948274687367, 24.2759551097326, 32.5602919366396, 
56.2960707237243, 8.75861931966005, 6.83960375748239), diff = c(1.85481342949123, 
2.49432519561113, 4.31245918456129, 23.6919764584793, 7.18552691948618, 
11.5880538495753)), .Names = c("Date", "Trans", "Cpu", "HeapUsage", 
"upper", "lower", "diff"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000170788>)
```

using data.table package I need to see if the Trans value for each date within upper and lower limits:

```
final<-final[,inside:=ifelse(Cpu>=lower || Cpu=<upper,1,0),by=c("Date")]
```

looks like not working with OR any ideas

Comment: you probably want to use `|` rather than `||` so that the inner part becomes: `ifelse(Cpu>=lower | Cpu<=upper,1,0)`. I just reversed the `=<` to `<=` as well.

Comment: @lmo, I've tried that. I get this error: Error: unexpected '=' in "final<-final[,inside:=ifelse(Cpu>=lower | Cpu="

Comment: `final[, inside:=ifelse(Cpu>=lower & Cpu<=upper, 1, 0)]`

Comment: The symbol is `<=` not `=<`.

Comment: @ytk, it worked, can you post it as an answer. I'll accept it.